# Uppercase styles applied to lowercase classes

Tags: html, css

In my knowledge HTML/CSS classes are case sensitive. However I'm experiencing the contrary.

[image]

Can I somehow make it case sensitive?

Comment: Where/What is question?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey How this could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

CSS itself is case insensitive, but selectors from HTML (class and id) are case sensitive:

The case-sensitivity of document language element names in selectors depends on the document language. For example, in HTML, element names are case-insensitive, but in XML they are case-sensitive

Answer (score -1):

Id, class and tag selectors  (like `#elemId`, .`myClass`, `BODY`) are case-insensitive. But selector like `[my-attr=someVal]` is case-sensitive, you can also try `[my-attr=someVal i]` - should force case-insensitive comparision.

Comment: The very first thing you learn about CSS is that IDs & classes are case sensitive.